# Does spring cloud gateway/loadbalancer keep the connection alive?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I have set up a Docker Swarm with the `whoami` service that is replicated 20 times.  From the gateway container when I do `wget -qO - whoami` or the `wget -qO - 10.0.x.x` IP address I get random whoami replicas.  However, when I do a similar thing on Spring Cloud Gateway it keeps on hitting the same replica.

Is there something in Spring Cloud Gateway or Load Balancer that keeps the connection stuck to the same node?

Also is it possible to disable that so I can test round robin

BOM is `set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.1")`

Relevant blocks of application.yml.  No discovery just a simple route.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: after_route
          uri: http://whoami2
          predicates:
            - Path=/who
```

Yields the following output

```
 spring-docker   rework [!⇡] via ☕ v17.32 
❯ curl  http://localhost:28080/who
Hostname: cef30a15e0e8
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.0.3.233
IP: 172.18.0.6
RemoteAddr: 10.0.3.22:54676
GET /who HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami2
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
Accept: */*
Forwarded: proto=http;host="localhost:28080";for="10.0.0.2:36624"
X-B3-Parentspanid: 264246902b820058
X-B3-Sampled: 1
X-B3-Spanid: 2727f63f28f4f775
X-B3-Traceid: 264246902b820058
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.0.2
X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:28080
X-Forwarded-Port: 28080
X-Forwarded-Proto: http


 spring-docker   rework [!⇡] via ☕ v17.32 
❯ curl  http://localhost:28080/who
Hostname: cef30a15e0e8
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.0.3.233
IP: 172.18.0.6
RemoteAddr: 10.0.3.22:54676
GET /who HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami2
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
Accept: */*
Forwarded: proto=http;host="localhost:28080";for="10.0.0.2:36626"
X-B3-Parentspanid: 37f7bcc012a2f20e
X-B3-Sampled: 1
X-B3-Spanid: 9a39133b80384588
X-B3-Traceid: 37f7bcc012a2f20e
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.0.2
X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:28080
X-Forwarded-Port: 28080
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

Older with the discovery

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  cloud:
    gateway:
#      fail-on-route-definition-error: false
      routes: []
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          url-expression: "uri"
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                patterns: "metadata['path']"
          filters:
            - RemoveRequestHeader='Cookie'
            - RemoveRequestHeader='X-B3-TraceId'
            - name: Retry
              args:
                retries: 3
              methods:
                - GET
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "metadata['path.regexp']"
                replacement: "metadata['path.replacement']"
#    inetutils:
#      ignoredInterfaces:
#        - docker0
#        - veth.*
#        - eth3
#    loadbalancer:
##      enabled: false
#      ribbon:
#        enabled: false
#      cache:
#        enabled: false
```

Comment: What is your gateway configuration? And versions?